# How to pass user preferences to each view in my MVC4 without to manually add it to my hundred of viewmodels

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have preferences stored for users (date format, language, currency symbol, etc).
Now, in my views I need to use those preferences to display dates or to display the currency with the correct symbol.

The problem is that since I have hundreds of viewmodels (actually a mix of models and viewmodels), in order to have this preferences object in my views I need to add a property in each VM and load that property in the controller. This will work, but is kind of smelly.

I thought of making all my viewmodels inherit from a `BaseViewModel` where the preferences property could be set. This will help me in having the property defined once, but I still need to load it in each controller's action once VM is instanciated.

**So, how should I do in order to avoid this and have access to the preferences in all my views?**

May be this is a good use of the `ViewData` and "injecting" the `Preferences` object into it, in an action filter?

Comment: an action filter is probably the best way to go. Viewbag or ViewData, either way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up creating an action filter this way:

```
public class IncludePreferencesAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{       
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
        var controller = filterContext.Controller as MyBaseController;

        if (controller != null)
        {
           controller.ViewBag.MyPref = controller.GetUserPreferences();
        }
    }
}
```

In the Controller action I need to use preferences I decorated it with `[IncludePreferences]`.

Then, in the view I do:

```
@{
   var pref = ViewBag.MyPref as MyPreferences;
}
```

This way, I don`t need to change my ViewModels, and only on those actions that need preferences it is loaded.